# Second selenium test is started before first one is completed

Tags: selenium, testng, autotest

I have two Selenium tests to run one after another. I have waiters injected into tests which wait for elements to become visible before interaction with them.
The issue is that sometimes second test is starting during waiting for the element to load in the first test.

This is waiter:

```
public void waitElementIsVisible(String locator) {
    logger.info("Waiting for element with locator " + locator + " to load in " + driver.getCurrentUrl() + " page");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locator)));
}
```

This is method that uses waiter:

```
protected void clickJs(String locator){
    waiters.waitElementIsVisible(locator);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement el = findPageElementByXpath(locator);
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el);
}
```

This is method that uses javascript click stated above:

```
public ActivitiesPage goToActivitiesPage(){
    clickJs(activitiesPage);
    return new ActivitiesPage();
}
```

And these are tests:

```
@Test
public void doSuccessfulLoginTest(){
    LoginPage page = new LoginPage();
    page.doSuccessfulLogin("ir2.0bb16be1@mailosaur.in", "qwerty").
    goToActivitiesPage(). 
            goToSignUpFormsPage().
    clickCreateSignupFormButton().
    specifySignUpFormName(Helper.getCurrentDateAndTime()).
    clickNextButton().
    selectLayout().
    clickNextButton().
    clickNextButton().
    clickNextButton(); 

    try {
        System.out.println("assertions");
        Assert.assertEquals(getDriver().getCurrentUrl().contains("dashboard"), true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void doSuccessfulLoginTestAndPublishSignupForm(){
    ActivitiesPage ap = new ActivitiesPage();
    ap.goToSignUpFormsPage().
    clickCreateSignupFormButton().
    specifySignUpFormName(Helper.getCurrentDateAndTime()).
    clickNextButton().
    selectLayout().
    clickNextButton().
    clickNextButton().
    clickNextButton(); 

    try {
        System.out.println("assertions");
        Assert.assertEquals(getDriver().getCurrentUrl().contains("subscribe"), true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Second test is started at **goToActivitiesPage()** method of first test if element inside it is being  waited for.

Have I can make sure that first test is completed before second is started?

Comment: You didn't provide the tests methods, but if you are not running them in parallel, if the second test started it means the first one ended. In your case the cause is probably an exception in the `waitElementIsVisible` method.

Comment: can you add your code ? It will be clear to identify the problem.

Comment: added code in description

Comment: As Guy said, your first test has to finish before second will start. Your first test probably failed because of some exception or even timeout.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are calling "separated methods annotated with @Test" as 2 selenium tests.
only possibility of happening this is:
the tests are configured to run in parallel. else they will always run sequentially, check test report to identify the failure reasons. if so and if you are using testNg then it can be resolved simply by using 1 of the beautiful property called [dependsOnMethods](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)  (
Ex.

```
@Test
public void test1() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"test1"}) //test2 will wait until test1 is finished
public void test2() {}
```

**Hint to debug:** unless specified parallel run, tests always run sequentially.  check test report to identify the failure reason(s).